# Working with .qr2 reports in .NET?

Tags: .net, reporting, quickreports

We use an ERP that has a bunch of reports in QuickReport format (.qr2). From what I could search, Quickreports has an interface for Delphi but not for .NET.

Anyone know if there's a (preferably free/OSS) solution for converting .qr2 reports to something I could work with in C#? Or a component for reading these reports directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is a .NET version of QuickReports supported in Delphi 2005 and Delphi 2006](http://www.qusoft.com/delphilegacy.html).  You have to get the (non-free) "professional" version of QuickReports to get the .NET support, however.  It's not included in the "standard" edition. Delphi 2005 and Delphi 2006 both support C#, but I have never tried the .NET version of QuickReports, with either Delphi for .NET or C#. I can't tell you how well it works.

Also, Qsoft is [planning to release a C# version of their tool](http://www.qusoft.com/Roadmap.html), though it appears to be behind schedule.